# Como manejar los estados del navigationbar bloc flutter?

Tags: flutter, bloc

Tengo un problema con el manejo de los estados. Normalmente utilizo el método Provider. Pero estoy comenzando con el patrón Bloc. Y necesito administrar el estado del home, ya que es un mapa y lo necesito para mantener el estado y no volver a dibujar cada vez que se cambia la página, es decir, si muevo la pantalla donde esta el mapa y cambio de tab, al regresar vuelvo a ver el mapa en la posición donde lo dejé. Ese sería el panorama ideal que quiero lograr.

En mi código tengo lo siguiente para manejar el cambio de pantallas:

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  final screens = <Widget>[
    HomeScreen(),
    MarketScreen(),
    ActivityPage(),
    AccountPage(),
  ];

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();
  ProxyAnimation transitionAnimation =
      ProxyAnimation(kAlwaysDismissedAnimation);

  BottomNavigationBarBloc _barBloc;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _barBloc = BlocProvider.of<BottomNavigationBarBloc>(context);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<BottomNavigationBarBloc, BottomNavigationBarState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is HomeState) {
          return buildHomepage(currentIndex: state.index);
        }
        if (state is MarketState) {
          return buildHomepage(currentIndex: state.index);
        }
        if (state is ActivityState) {
          return buildHomepage(currentIndex: state.index);
        }
        if (state is AccountState) {
          return buildHomepage(currentIndex: state.index);
        }
        return Container(
          color: Colors.cyan[200],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Scaffold buildHomepage({int currentIndex}) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: PageStorage(
              bucket: bucket,
              child: screens[currentIndex],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        fixedColor: Colors.cyan[300],
        elevation: 5,
        onTap: (index) {
          if (index == 0) {
            return _barBloc..add(LoadHome());
          }
          if (index == 1) {
            return _barBloc..add(LoadMarket());
          }
          if (index == 2) {
            return _barBloc..add(LoadActivity());
          }
          if (index == 3) {
            return _barBloc..add(LoadAccount());
          }
          return _barBloc..add(LoadHome());
        },
        items: [
          _buildTabBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
          _buildTabBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home_repair_service_outlined), label: 'Feed'),
          _buildTabBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.whatshot_outlined), label: 'Ranking'),
          _buildTabBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_sharp), label: 'Account')
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildTabBarItem({final Widget icon, final String label}) {
    return BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: icon,
      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
      title: Text(
        label,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahí podrías usar un IndexedStack en lugar de builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is HomeState) {
          return buildHomepage(currentIndex: state.index);
        }

Comment: El IndexedStack debería ir en un body por lo que tengo entendido. Que pasaria con el cuerpo del blockbuilder?

Comment: hmm, hice un playlist con 3 videos, ahí hago una app completa desde 0 con clean architecture, flutter_bloc, inyección de dependencias, etc , en una parte (en el 1er video), hago el manejo de tabs con IndexedStack, puedes verlo -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7FjCWHmP9Y&list=PLrS57q8gZKG_6vUaHN8lJytqq4cVZKu2T